# Tkinter app not initiating after assigning label with variable using the .config method

Tags: python, tkinter, ticker

I am trying to write a simple bitcoin ticker using the coinmarketcap module.

When I run the following code, the tkinter app does not load. No errors are given. I think I am calling everything properly but not sure what else could be at fault.

code:

```
from coinmarketcap import Market
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

def btc_ticker():
    while True:
        coinmarketcap = Market()
        btc_tick = coinmarketcap.ticker(1, convert ='GBP')
        btc_price = btc_tick['data']['quotes']['GBP']['price']
        #print(btc_price)
        time.sleep(2)
        btc_p.config(text = str(btc_price))
        root.after(2, btc_ticker)

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')

btc_p = Label(root, font=('consolas', 20, 'bold'), text="0",width =10, bg='black', fg='white')
btc_p.grid(row=0, column =0)

btc_ticker()

root.mainloop()
```

I can print the variable 'btc_price' so the assignment of this to btc_p through the .configure method should not be an issue.

Comment: Your `btc_ticker` has an infinite while loop which will prevent your `root.mainloop()` from being called...maybe you should consider re-organizing your code...

Comment: Because of that `while` loop inside `btc_ticker()` you never execute `root.mainloop()` thus don't display anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem with your code was that you had `while True` loop before `root.mainlop()` which could't let it execute. Way to handle constant updates with `tkinter` is to use `root.after()`, which you implemented but not correctly. I removed `while` loop and left `root.after` at end of your function to let `mainloop()` execute. Also note that first argument of `root.after` is time in milliseconds, so to make your program wait 2 seconds that argument should be 2000.

```
from coinmarketcap import Market
from tkinter import *

def btc_ticker():
    coinmarketcap = Market()
    btc_tick = coinmarketcap.ticker(1, convert ='GBP')
    btc_price = btc_tick['data']['quotes']['GBP']['price']
    #print(btc_price)
    btc_p.config(text = str(btc_price))
    root.after(2000, btc_ticker)

root = Tk()
root.configure(background='black')

btc_p = Label(root, font=('consolas', 20, 'bold'), text="0",width =10, bg='black', fg='white')
btc_p.grid(row=0, column =0)

btc_ticker()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Great, I didn't realize the while loop would prevent the mainloop from running!